# How to use Apache mod_headers to append a Cookie?

Tags: apache, http-headers, request-headers

**My Scenario**

I want to add a cookie to the existing cookies sent by the user in the request header.

**What I tried**

So I decided to use [`RequestHeader` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

```
RequestHeader append Cookie "foo=bar"
```

The only problem is that RequestHeader appends the new value per definition with a comma (,) not with a semicolon (;). So my new cookies is "merged" with the old one in a strange way (probably because of the missing semicolon).

[image]

Or

```
RequestHeader append Cookie " foo=bar"
```

[image]

> The request header is appended to any existing header of the same
>   name. When a new value is merged onto an existing header it is
>   separated from the existing header with a comma. This is the HTTP
>   standard way of giving a header multiple values. [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

**My question**

Am I missing something or is RequestHeader not the right directive?

Environment: Apache/2.4.20, PHP/5.5.35, Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the add method instead of append, also its not called Cookie, its Set-Cookie, Cookie, is just the name you see in the browser.

```
Header add Set-Cookie "mycookie=value; path=/; expires=Thu, 13 Dec 2018 13:31:00 -0000; HttpOnly"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that using append for cookies does not work as expected.

After analysing what I actually needed, decided that setting a new RequestHeader was enough.